# Why is a tuple of falsey objects truthy?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Came across this in a recent project and was curious as to why this is the case.

```
test_ = None
test_1 = []
test_2 = ([], None)

if test_:
    print('hello')

if test_1:
    print('hello')

if test_2:
    print('hello')
> hello
```

Comment: Because it's non-empty. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [by definition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) non-empty tuples evaluates to `True`.